# Why in proof of f+g measurable we use $q \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation

It is known that for proof of $$f+g: \Omega \to \mathbb{\bar{R}}, \omega \mapsto f(\omega) + g(\omega)$$ is measurable, that is:

$$\left \{ f+g<t \right \}=\bigcup_{a,b\in \mathbb{Q}, a+b<t} \left \{ f < a \right \} \cap \left \{ g<b \right \}$$

My question is why $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and not in $\mathbb{R}$? What would be if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: set $\mathbb Q$ is countable and $\mathbb R$ is uncountable.

Comment: @dust05 Okay, but by definition of measurability is that $\left \{  \omega | f(\omega) < t \right \} \in \mathfrak{F}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathfrak{F}$ is sigma-algebra.

Comment: $\{f < a\}$ and $\{g < b\}$ are measurable so the intersection is. And the countable union of measurable sets is again measurable. As a consequence $f + g$ is measurable. Note that the uncountable union of measurable set is not always measurable.

Comment: @dust05 thanks for explanation!

Comment: Methinks you've omitted a condition $a+b\leq t$.  The countable union of measurable sets is measurable but the uncountable isn't, e.g., because all sets are uncountable unions of singletons.

Comment: @ForgotALot you are right! I should edit it